# Mac OSX: Android Studio quit unexpectedly on first time startup

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I just downloaded the latest version of Android studio and tried to run it, but I got an error immediately saying "Android Studio quit unexpectedly".

I followed the advice from similar threads to set the STUDIO_SDK version (in the terminal) but that doesn't seem to have helped. I have tried opening the app from the launcher and from the terminal but I get the same error both ways.

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home
$ echo $STUDIO_SDK
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk
$ grep -A 1 "JVMVersion" /Applications/Android\ Studio.app//Contents/Info.plist
      <key>JVMVersion</key>
      <string>1.8*,1.8+</string>
```

What else am I missing?

There is no idea.log file but the problem report is below:

```
Process:         launchd [11964]
Path:            /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
Identifier:      com.google.android.studio
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [9844]

Date/Time:       2016-11-23 09:24:19.877 +0000
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          7418 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           21
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   18
Anonymous UUID:                      69831F0A-5E39-44B1-A534-CB06C4589328

Crashed Thread:  Unknown

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007fff5fc01028

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000055  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x0000000000000000
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff5fc01028  rfl: 0x0000000000010203  cr2: 0x00007fff5fc01028
Logical CPU: 2

Binary images description not available


External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 1
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 47204
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

Model: MacBookPro8,1, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.68f99
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 384 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533642465238432D48392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533642465238432D48392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.198.19.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.8f17, 2 service, 11 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: ST9500325ASG, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS31N
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 5
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 7
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0252, 0xfa120000 / 4
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

Comment: Check console and try to obtain some log to see what the crash is… with this information alone it's impossible to tell what's going on. What version of OS X do you have? What computer? Do other Java apps work? Can you compile java apps from the command line? etc. etc. etc.

Comment: I am using OS X 10.7.5 on a 2011 Macbook Pro. The javac and java commands work fine for me in the console. There is no idea.log file anywhere on the file system but there is a crash report which I will update on this post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my problem. Android Studio is not supported by OS X 10.7.5. On the [download page](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) the system requirements state that I need 10.8.5 at a minimum:

> Mac® OS X® 10.8.5 or higher, up to 10.12 (macOS Sierra)

Comment: Glad to hear you found your answer!

Comment: Thanks Martin, me too.